# Error "Could not find wsdl:binding operation info for web method" in OSGi Karaf

Tags: java, wsdl, osgi, apache-felix, karaf

I'm developing a client which should run in OSGi container. I'm using the stubs generated by cxf-codegen-plugin. The following Standalone application works fine:

```
  public class MyClient {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.lang.Exception{

        String endpointT = "http://myService/endpoint/";

        MyServicess = new MyService( );
        MyServicePortType port = ss.MyServicePort();
        BindingProvider provider = (BindingProvider) port;
        Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);

        client.getRequestContext().put(Message.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS, endpointT) ;

        System.out.println("Invoking findEventManager...");

        System.out.println(port.callService());



    }
}
```

When I try the same thing in an OSGi container (I'm using karaf which use the felix implementation of OSGi). It doesn't work! and show me this excepption `javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not find wsdl:binding operation info for web method callService.` . The code looks as following:

```
@Component(name="RemoteExample", immediate=true)
@Service
public class RemoteExampleImpl extends Thread implements IRemoteExample  {

    private Boolean running =false;
    @Activate
    protected void activate(ComponentContext context)  {
        running =true;
        this.start();
    }

     public void run() {

         boolean cont = true;

         while (cont && running) {
             String endpointT = "http://myService/endpoint/";

            MyServicess = new MyService( );
            MyServicePortType port = ss.MyServicePort();
            BindingProvider provider = (BindingProvider) port;
            Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);

            client.getRequestContext().put(Message.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS, endpointT) ;

            System.out.println("Invoking findEventManager...");

            System.out.println(port.callService());
         }
     }

    @Deactivate
    protected void deactivate(ComponentContext context) {
        running = false;
        mLogger.info("LocalExampleImpl deactivated");
    }
}
```

How I can make this code work?

Comment: Do you import the right packages in your bundle? Might want to take a look at CXF it plays really nicely with OSGi.

Comment: If was wrong should be wrong in both examples. I use maven for the dependencies.